# Multiple textures one mesh

Tags: texturing, subdivision-surface

This is not the standard question already on the site so please do not put on hold read first:

I am working on a mesh with heavy use of a subsurf and so the base topology is quite different to what i'm used to, my problem is, the way I know for applying multiple textures (in cycles) is you select a face then "assign" a texture to that particular face. However, my question is, is there another way in which to apply multiple textures in blender? Here is my situation:

[image]

Now, I want the texture to the LEFT of the highlighted line here:

[image]

but i cannot simply create the extra geometry as that affects the shape of the mesh with the effects of the subsurf. So basically, how do I create a face for the texture without affecting the actual geometry (if that's even possible), any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: not so clear, to me, but: applying subsurf won't help you here?

Comment: I don't see why your question is that different from others; it looks like you're searching for texture masks. You unwrap the mesh, then add material, a texture (procedural or not, whatever) and  use it as factor for mixing 2+ materials. That way you're independent on mesh geometry but you are on the texture resolution.